# efetch nucleotide -> protein ids

Tags: genome, phylogeny, phylogenetics, efetch

I'm downloading translated viral genomes initially via Blast - which had shortcomings - and now by `efetch`.

What I want to do is obtain a complete list of all translated protein ids from a nucleotide Genbank entry.

```
efetch -db nucleotide -format gpc -id MT039887 | xtract -insd ....
```

The protein id and the translated gene sequences are within the `efetch -db nucleotide -format gpc -id MT039887` output ... but how do I use `xtract` to parse them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the cds in fasta format, try:

```
esearch -db nucleotide -query MT039887 | efetch -format fasta_cds_na
```

And for the proteins sequence in fasta format:

```
elink -db nucleotide -target protein -id MT039887 | efetch -format fasta
```

Comment: Wow!! and thank you. Thats the answer ... days like this BioSE works. @zorbax I owe you. "Acknowledgements" thank you heading your way (thats not a metaphor).

Answer (score 1):

In case you are still interested in just getting the protein ids and not sequence, you can use `xtract` like this:

```
efetch -db nucleotide -format gpc -id MT039887 | xtract  -insd CDS gene product protein_id 
MT039887.1  orf1ab  orf1ab polyprotein           QHZ00388.1
MT039887.1  S       surface glycoprotein         QHZ00389.1
MT039887.1  orf3a   orf3a protein                QHZ00390.1
MT039887.1  E       envelope protein             QHZ00391.1
MT039887.1  M       membrane glycoprotein        QHZ00392.1
MT039887.1  orf6    orf6 protein                 QHZ00393.1
MT039887.1  orf7a   orf7a protein                QHZ00394.1
MT039887.1  orf8    orf8 protein                 QHZ00395.1
MT039887.1  N       nucleocapsid phosphoprotein  QHZ00396.1
MT039887.1  orf10   orf10 protein                QHZ00397.1
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really useful.